# Python - Assigning variables to a json list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I've been trying to figure this one out,
so there is this api i'm trying to get information from, such as game scores.

the api list content looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "team_id": "FALCONS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9524691Z",
    "wins": 11,
    "crow_size": 19563,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:17:16.0000000Z",
      "data": "4e7a-bf0c-a97e5f32f58b",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "CARDINALS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9212380Z",
    "wins": 14,
    "crow_size": 26000,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:25.6850000Z",
      "data": "42ec-8326-445a22ea460f",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "BUFFALO",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.7961978Z",
    "wins": 16,
    "crow_size": 34200,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:07:50.0000000Z",
      "data": "44b7-86c1-6b969fccbe2e",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to print scores from highest wins to lowest wins:

```
BUFFALO 16
CARDINALS 17
FALCONS 11
```

It's a really large list, so i only want an specific number of teams,
right now i've been able to get only the scores with this:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import datetime
import heapq
from pprint import pprint


url = 'api url'
getscore = requests.get(url)
getscore = json.loads(getscore.content)


lookup = ["CARDINALS", "BUFFALO"]



for x in getscore:
    for ex in lookup:
        if ex == x["team_id"]:
            print(x["team_id"], x["wins"])
```

with the above code i can get the scores but unorganized,
so i would like to do this from highest wins to lowest wins,
i would like some help with this as i want to learn more.

also is it possible to get the percentage difference between the highest score / with the lowest score? something like this

```
BUFFALO 16       percentage difference is = 10 percent
CARDINALS 17
FALCONS 11
```

thank you guys for any reply

Answer (score 3):

Using a `list comprehension` and `sort`

```
lookup = ["CARDINALS", "BUFFALO"]
data = [(x["team_id"], x["wins"]) for x in getscore if x["team_id"] in lookup]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(data)
```

**Outout:**

```
[('BUFFALO', 16), ('CARDINALS', 14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def lookup(N, data):
    arranged = sorted(data, key = lambda x: ~x.get('wins'))
    for val in arranged[:N]:
        yield val['team_id'], val['wins']

parsed = lookup(3, data)

for p in parsed:
    print p

('BUFFALO', 16)
('CARDINALS', 14)
('FALCONS', 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I can be of help, to answer both your questions, for organizing, as well as getting the percentage difference.

1. Organizing.

So, if you want to order the results, from the highest to the lowest, then you will need to use the ***sorted*** function. How will you go about this? Well, here is an example of how you would sort your list of python objects.

```
my_teams = [
  {
    "team_id": "FALCONS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9524691Z",
    "wins": 11,
    "crow_size": 19563,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:17:16.0000000Z",
      "data": "4e7a-bf0c-a97e5f32f58b",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "CARDINALS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9212380Z",
    "wins": 14,
    "crow_size": 26000,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:25.6850000Z",
      "data": "42ec-8326-445a22ea460f",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "BUFFALO",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.7961978Z",
    "wins": 16,
    "crow_size": 34200,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:07:50.0000000Z",
      "data": "44b7-86c1-6b969fccbe2e",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  }
]
```

Now to sort this from the highest win to the lowest, do this:

```
my_teams = list(sorted(my_teams, key=itemgetter('wins'), reverse=True))
```

What the above snipet does is that it will use the ***wins*** key to sort the list, returning a sorted set, which is then converted back to a list. Notice that there is ***reverse*** keyword, this is used to sort from the highest to the lowest(descending), since by default, the sorting will be from the lowest to the highest (ascending)

Another thing to notice is the ***itemgetter***. This is a method of operator and thus you will have to import it at the top from operator as such:

```
from operator import itemgetter
```

2. Getting percentage difference.

Now that you have already sorted your content. To get the percentage difference, simply do this:

```
percentage_difference = my_teams[0].get('wins') - my_teams[-1].get('wins')
```

***my_teams[0].get('wins')*** means you get the first item from your new sorted list, and then get it's *wins* attribute. You then subtract the last item's ***(my_teams[-1].get('wins'))*** *wins* attribute.

Let me know if I have been able to help you.